# Scala collection.breakOut doesn't work with case classes?

Tags: scala, collections

I am trying to parse the input data to case classes inside a TreeSet but it doesn't seem to work.

```
case class Block(letter: Char)
// This does not compile
val brokenBlocks: collection.immutable.TreeSet[Block] = "A B C".split(' ').map(letter => Block(letter(0)))(collection.breakOut)
// Although this compiles
val workingBlocks: collection.immutable.TreeSet[Int] = "A B C".split(' ').map(letter => letter(0).asDigit)(collection.breakOut)
```

Compilation error:

```
type mismatch;  found   : scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Any,Char,String]
required: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Array[String],Block,scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[Block]]
```

I am trying this in scala worksheet.

Comment: It's not it doesn't work. There is no implicit definition in scope to tell compiler how to build `TreeSet[Block]`. You need to implement one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No relation with case classes at all. If you had tried to build a List or a Vector it would have worked fine.

A TreeSet requires that there is an Ordering on its element's type. There is one on Int, but none on Block.

If you add one, say in the companion object

```
object Block {
   implicit val ordering: Ordering[Block] = Ordering.by(_.letter)
}
```

then it works.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know that. How did you find out? Compiler doesn't help here.

Comment: Yes, compiler gives quite misleading message. I also wonder how to "debug" such cases.